# Using CouchDB in a DAL-like way from web2py

Tags: python, database, couchdb, web2py

It looks like using CouchDB with the standard web2py DAL is still a ways off:

- [User suggestion for couchdb DAL in web2py](http://web2py.uservoice.com/forums/42577-general/suggestions/504597-add-dal-support-for-couchdb-mongodb-etc)
- [Discussion with mdipierro almost a year ago](http://www.mail-archive.com/web2py@googlegroups.com/msg29741.html)

I'm working on using CouchDB from web2py. python-couchdb looks fairly powerful and well designed but not particularly well documented. Does anybody have good examples of using CouchDB from in a DAL-like way? The best I've found is this [blog entry by David Watson](http://davidwatson.org/2008/02/python-couchdb-rocks.html), but it doesn't go into much depth. I'm looking for more.

Alternatively, I'll accept information about the status of CouchDB in web2py that is more recent.

Comment: [CouchDBKit](http://couchdbkit.org/) is excellent.

Comment: CouchDB is now supported (experimentally) by web2py DAL. We could use some testers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the file gluon/contrib/gql.py which overrides the DAL to work on GAE. couchdb would work very much the same. we have one partial implementation of MondoDB support. We have solved the problem of uuid vs autoincrement integer id. Joins us on the web2py mailing list to discuss more.

Comment: Thanks Massimo. I'll look at gql and consider joining the list.

Answer (score 2):

The new web2py DAL is in trunk (still being tested before release), and it looks like it will have [support for CouchDB and MongoDB](http://web2py.com/AlterEgo/default/show/272) (also [here](http://groups.google.com/group/web2py/msg/36f5861d03cc69a2) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/web2py/browse_frm/thread/de7e26eb4f83e7d7)), and probably more to come.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB has been working in web2py as of about 1/6/11. This is me talking with Massimo about the bugs, and subsequent fixes, here:

http://groups.google.com/group/web2py/browse_thread/thread/b110d60a4e13953e/9c6f46805d106d17?lnk=gst&q=couchdb#9c6f46805d106d17

I'm not sure if this has been promoted into the stable branch or not yet, so you may need to synch against trunk for this to work.